# function accidentally called when defining list

Tags: python, function

I'm new to Python and I've been working on a project that involves attributes of objects in a list --one of which is a function-- to be called at a later time. However, when I define the list the function is called without it being wanted.
For example in:

```
x=0
def activateitem():
    if x==1:
        print('item has been activated')
    else:
        print('function called')

item=['itemname','red',1,2,activateitem()]

x=1
```

The result is 'function called'. Is there a way to circumvent this without making the list a function as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to get the last element in the list to be equal to `item has been activated` or `function called`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked the function and thus the result was added to the list.
If that is not what you want, you can add the function itself to the list [without invoking it with the parentheses] and then invoke it later by accessing the function within the list [by its index in the list] and then invoking it.

```
>>> def foo():
...   print('hi')
... 
>>> l = [1,2,foo]
>>> l
[1, 2, <function foo at 0x7fed39328bf8>]
>>> l[2]()
hi
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the function to the list without calling it:

```
item=['itemname','red',1,2,activateitem]
```

Using the parenthesis calls the function.